# Does react-virtualized work inside a functional component?

Tags: react-virtualized

I am asking because the examples I've seen are all in es6 classes.

And: I refactored my es6 class to a functional component. Now no rows appear any more. And no error either. Seems like the row renderer simply renders no rows any more.

Comment: Yes, react-virtualized works within class or function components. You might have better luck getting help with you specific situation if you link to a Plnkr that shows some code and the problem you're describing.

Comment: thanks @brianvaughn, I must have messed up my code then. And THANKS A LOT for this great tool!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use function component with `react-virtualized`

Does it perform as well as class component? I have no idea, tell me in comment ;)

Example:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Grid, Typography} from '@material-ui/core'
import PackageItem from './PackageItem'
import {PackagesByCategory} from '../functions/src/types'
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import {WindowScroller, AutoSizer, List, ListRowRenderer, CellMeasurer, CellMeasurerCache} from 'react-virtualized'


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    container: {
        minHeight: "80vh",
        width: "100%"
    },
    title: {
        marginTop: 64,
    },
}))

const cache = new CellMeasurerCache({
    defaultHeight: 60,
    fixedWidth: true
});


const PackageCategoriesList = ({packagesByCategories}: PackageCategoriesList) => {
    const classes = useStyles()

    if(!packagesByCategories) {
        return <></>
    }

    const rowRender: ListRowRenderer = ({index, key, style, parent}) => {
        const packageByCategory = packagesByCategories[index]

        return <CellMeasurer
            cache={cache}
            columnIndex={0}
            key={key}
            overscanRowCount={10}
            parent={parent}
            rowIndex={index}
        >
            <Grid item key={key} style={style}>
                    <Typography variant="h1" className={classes.title}>
                        {packageByCategory.category.name}
                    </Typography>
                </Grid>
        </CellMeasurer>
    }

    return <div className={classes.container}>
        <WindowScroller
            scrollElement={window}>
            {({height, isScrolling, registerChild, onChildScroll, scrollTop}) => (
                <div className={classes.list}>
                    {console.log("re der list" , height, isScrolling, scrollTop)}
                    <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                        {({width}) => (
                            <div ref={registerChild}>
                                <List
                                    autoHeight
                                    height={height}
                                    isScrolling={isScrolling}
                                    onScroll={onChildScroll}
                                    overscanRowCount={2}
                                    rowCount={packagesByCategories.length}
                                    rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
                                    rowRenderer={rowRender}
                                    scrollTop={scrollTop}
                                    width={width}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </AutoSizer>
                </div>
            )}
        </WindowScroller>

    </div>
}

export default PackageCategoriesList
```

Comment: Nice response, any ideas for how to approach it if you need to provide a keyMapper and the keyMapper depends on the props of the functional component? Note that it needs to not recreate the cache each time since this is presumably expensive and will cause any child components you pass the cache into to re-render, potentially unnecessarily.

Comment: Never used keyMapper but maybe you could also have your own cache system if more specific functionnality are needed.